# How to exempt first row on moving up and down or how to auto arrange number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Html:

```
<table class="myTable" border="1" width="80%">
<tr >
    <td>1</td>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><button onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td></tr>
<tr>
        <td>2</td>
            <td>two</td> 
<td><button onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
<td><button onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
            <td>three</td> 
<td><button onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
<td><button onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>4</td>
            <td>four</td> 
<td><button onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
<td><button onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>5</td>
            <td>five</td> 
<td><button onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
<td><button onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
    </tr>
        </table>
```

Javascript:

```
function get_previoussibling(n)
{
    x=n.previousSibling;
    while (x.nodeType!=1)
      {
      x=x.previousSibling;
      }
    return x;
} 

function get_nextsibling(n)
{
    x=n.nextSibling;
    while ( x != null && x.nodeType!=1)
      {
      x=x.nextSibling;
      }
    return x;
} 
function MoveUp()
    {
        var table,
            row = this.parentNode;

        while ( row != null ) {
            if ( row.nodeName == 'TR' ) {
                break;
            }
            row = row.parentNode;
        }
        table = row.parentNode;
        table.insertBefore ( row, get_previoussibling( row ) );
    }

    function MoveDown()
    {
        var table,
            row = this.parentNode;

        while ( row != null ) {
            if ( row.nodeName == 'TR' ) {
                break;
            }
            row = row.parentNode;
        }
        table = row.parentNode;
        table.insertBefore ( row, get_nextsibling ( get_nextsibling( row ) ) );
    }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z5hroz4p/8/

I am moving up and down rows in a table.Mmy first column is numbering column it should remain unchanged.or while moving up and down arrows it should auto arrange number. how can I do it?

Comment: which number should arrange? can you explain with fiddle. am seeing there 4 columns.

Comment: @punitha subramani v first column 12345

Answer (score 0):

Loop all `tr` and add it's index to first `td`

```
$.each($('.myTable tr'), function(index, element){
    $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(index+1);
});
```

Comment: Can you suggest how to exempt first column from moving up and down.This solution doesn't suit me

Comment: @user3383271 than use double tables, first table is only with numbers for rows, second has movable content.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be to wrap your first row in  tag and all other row in  tag. This way you won't have to modify your javascript ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5hroz4p/10/))

```
<table class="myTable" border="1" width="80%">
<thead>    
<tr >
    <td></td>
    <td>one</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<tr>
        <td></td>
            <td>two</td> 
<td><button onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
<td><button onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
            <td>three</td> 
<td><button onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
<td><button onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
            <td>four</td> 
<td><button onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
<td><button onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
            <td>five</td> 
<td><button onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
<td><button onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its working.

Remove this line in css, table.myTable tr td:first-child:before { content: counter(rowNumber, decimal);

```
    <table class="myTable" border="1" width="80%">
    <tr >
        <td>1</td>
        <td>one</td>
        <td><button onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
        <td><button onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td></tr>
    <tr>
            <td>2</td>
                <td>two</td> 
    <td><button onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
                <td>three</td> 
    <td><button onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>4</td>
                <td>four</td> 
    <td><button onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>5</td>
                <td>five</td> 
    <td><button onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></td>
        </tr>
            </table>
```